# How to properly append lines to already existing file

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, file-writing

I looked over the internet trying to find a solution for writing line by line into a file in c. I found solutions like changing the mode of `fopen()` to `w+`, `wt`, `wb` but it did not work for me. I even read to put `\r` instead of `\n` in the end of the line but still when I try to write to the file the only thing that is written there is the last line.

```
    FILE *log = NULL;
    log = fopen(fileName, "w");
    if (log == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! can't open log file.");
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf(log, "you bought %s\n", pro[item].name);
    fclose(log);
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `fopen(whatever, "a")` is what you need.

Comment: "write line by line to a file" would (to me at least) imply that you are writing multiple lines at a time, where instead here you want to *append* to a file, writing one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because everytime you execute fprintf in "w" mode, **the log gets overwritten** with the new contents as the file was not opened in the 'append' mode but in 'write' mode.

Better thing would be to use:

```
fopen("filename", "a");
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can have two approaches,

**Case 1** *(Opening / closing multiple times, write one value at a time)*

You need to open the file in *append* mode to preserve the previous content. Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) of `fopen()` for `a` or *append* mode.

**Case 2** *(Opening / Closing once, writing all the values at a stretch)*

you need to put the `fprintf()` statement in some kind of `loop` to get all the elements printed, i.e., the *index* (`item`) value goes from `0` to *some max* value.